# When running UI Tests on an XCode Server Bot, is it possible to see the actual simulator running?

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcode-bots

We have set up a Xcode project with alot of the new UI tests that run the app and test the user interface. Its nice to see the tests running in the simulator when i run them on my local mac.

We have setup this project with XCode server and a Bot is running it. We have a monitor connected to this mac thats running the server, and can show the Bots running. I was wondering if there is a way to show the actual simulator on the server machine when it is running the UI tests?

Comment: I think the closest you will get is the saved snapshots from failed tests.

Answer (score 0):

The simulator should run and be visible.  If you've setup the server with a separate account for the bots, all you have to do is switch users to that account to see the simulator.  It's possible to have multiple users logged in at once.

You don't even need a monitor, use Apple's built in desktop sharing and login remotely.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to open the simulator by running the app or running a test on it. Don't close the simulator. Now if you start the bot, u can monitor the status of the test cases on that simulator in the screen.